# Getting error while connecting with other nodes in cluster

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, galera, mysql-cluster

I create Galera cluster for mysql 8, when i'm restarting the nodes it is connecting in the cluster but after few seconds its getting disconnected. Please help me to fix this issue. Please see the logs-

```
2021-05-09T19:29:47.376651Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23-26.6) starting as process 4361
    
2021-05-09T19:29:47.392229Z 0 [Warning] [MY-000000] [WSREP] P: access file(/var/lib/mysql//gvwstate.dat) failed(No such file or directory)
    
    2021-05-09T19:30:17.947192Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000000] [WSREP] P: failed to open gcomm backend connection: 110: failed to reach primary view: 110 (Connection timed out)
    
    at /home/galera/galera-4-26.4.8+1focal/gcomm/src/pc.cpp:connect():160
    
    2021-05-09T19:30:17.947399Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000000] [WSREP] P: /home/galera/galera-4-26.4.8+1focal/gcs/src/gcs_core.cpp:gcs_core_open():219: Failed to open backend connection: -110 (Connection timed out)
    
    2021-05-09T19:30:17.948105Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000000] [WSREP] P: /home/galera/galera-4-26.4.8+1focal/gcs/src/gcs.cpp:gcs_open():1631: Failed to open channel 'galera4' at 'gcomm://192.168.1.4,192.168.1.5,192.168.1.6': -110 (Connection timed out)
    
    2021-05-09T19:30:17.948139Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000000] [WSREP] P: gcs connect failed: Connection timed out
    
    2021-05-09T19:30:17.949193Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000000] [WSREP] wsrep::connect(gcomm://192.168.1.4,192.168.1.5,192.168.1.6) failed: 7
    
    2021-05-09T19:30:17.949217Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
    
    2021-05-09T19:30:17.967785Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.23-26.6) MySQL Wsrep Server - GPL.
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Is there connectivity to the IP addresses mentioned in the error messages? Are the servers protected by firewalls? An internet search may also be useful. Your problem seems to have several possible causes, for example see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37212127/mariadb-gcomm-backend-connection-failed-110.